# Why Request has been truncated while uploading an excel of 350000 rows in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, nginx, file-upload

I am trying to upload an excel file of 44MB having 350,000 rows in the file. Does the rows inside the excel file matter while uploading in PHP ?

max_input_vars is 6000 in php.ini. Is it related to my issue ?

Comment: PHP or the webserver can enforce a max upload size.

Comment: This is the current config of the webserver 
post_max_size = 102M, 
upload_max_filesize = 100M

Comment: try to increase max_execution_time in php.ini file

Comment: @vivekmodi Thanks a ton!

I was struggling with it since yesterday night. Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: please give positive point if it solve your problem

Comment: @vivekmodi Please repost your comment as an answer for me to accept your input as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to increase max_execution_time in php.ini file